# postgresql query takes forever

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have the below query which takes forever (several days), if you can provide any help on how to improve it would be great
The server has 2 xeon e5-2630 v3 CPUs (8 cores, 16 threads each) with 128 GB RAM and SSD disk, postgres 11.

```
        SELECT distinct on (location_signals.p_key)  ooh_data.*, 
        location_signals."Lat" AS did_lat, location_signals."Lon" As did_lon,  location_signals.device,
        location_signals.timestamp AS did_timestamp, location_signals.p_key AS did_p_key
        FROM ooh_data , 
        location_signals 
        WHERE ST_DWithin( 
           ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ooh_data.offset_lon, ooh_data.offset_lat), 4326)::geography,
           ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(location_signals."Lon", location_signals."Lat"), 4326)::geography,
           100
        ) 
        ORDER BY location_signals.p_key;
```

location_signals has 300 million records, and ooh_data has 6000 records

here's an explain by greatly limiting the selection:

```
explain analyse        SELECT  distinct on (location_signals.p_key)  ooh_data.*
        FROM ooh_data , 
        location_signals 
        WHERE ST_DWithin( 
        ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ooh_data.offset_lon, ooh_data.offset_lat), 4326)::geography,
        ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(location_signals."Lon", location_signals."Lat"), 4326)::geography,
        100
        ) 
        AND ooh_data.p_key > 5700
        AND location_signals.timestamp > '2019-05-31 23:57:00'
        ORDER BY location_signals.p_key;
```

result:

```
QUERY PLAN
Unique  (cost=100551.80..100551.80 rows=1 width=84) (actual time=305.190..305.193 rows=2 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=100551.80..100551.80 rows=1 width=84) (actual time=305.189..305.190 rows=3 loops=1)
        Sort Key: location_signals.p_key
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Gather  (cost=1029.18..100551.79 rows=1 width=84) (actual time=305.180..310.644 rows=3 loops=1)
              Workers Planned: 1
              Workers Launched: 1
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=29.18..99551.69 rows=1 width=84) (actual time=195.851..277.511 rows=2 loops=2)
                    Join Filter: (((st_setsrid(st_makepoint(ooh_data.offset_lon, ooh_data.offset_lat), 4326))::geography && _st_expand((st_setsrid(st_makepoint(location_signals."Lon", location_signals."Lat"), 4326))::geography, '100'::double precision)) AND ((st_setsrid(st_makepoint(location_signals."Lon", location_signals."Lat"), 4326))::geography && _st_expand((st_setsrid(st_makepoint(ooh_data.offset_lon, ooh_data.offset_lat), 4326))::geography, '100'::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin((st_setsrid(st_makepoint(ooh_data.offset_lon, ooh_data.offset_lat), 4326))::geography, (st_setsrid(st_makepoint(location_signals."Lon", location_signals."Lat"), 4326))::geography, '100'::double precision, true))
                    Rows Removed by Join Filter: 139156
                    ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on location_signals  (cost=28.89..2814.14 rows=1482 width=24) (actual time=1.144..10.886 rows=1288 loops=2)
                          Recheck Cond: ("timestamp" > '2019-05-31 23:57:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                          Heap Blocks: exact=1396
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_timestamp  (cost=0.00..28.27 rows=2519 width=0) (actual time=1.355..1.356 rows=2577 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: ("timestamp" > '2019-05-31 23:57:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                    ->  Index Scan using ooh_data_pkey on ooh_data  (cost=0.28..5.35 rows=107 width=76) (actual time=0.004..0.025 rows=108 loops=2577)
                          Index Cond: (p_key > 5700)
Planning Time: 0.424 ms
Execution Time: 310.738 ms
```

appreciating any help , thanks

Comment: Trim down your query until explain can give you an answer, and then find out the one thing you add that breaks it.

Comment: As a note, joining on 300MM records is going to take forever unless that data is indexed properly. The query you're doing may not be able to make use of indexes and may have to do 300MM * 6K queries, or in other words, 1.8 trillion comparisons.

Comment: thanks, will try that...do you have any alternative suggestions? we had a logic built where it would go by each individual ooh_data entry and query to that, but it's practically the same i think, was hoping maybe this might go faster through 1 query rather than 1.8 trillion queries

Comment: Might be able to save some calculations by pre-processing the `ooh_data` table and creating the a column for `ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ooh_data.offset_lon, ooh_data.offset_lat), 4326)::geography`.  Then use the new column in the subquery.  Saves re-calculating that part over and over.

Comment: It really depends on how you're using PostGIS. Sometimes it's able to understand what you're saying and use an index, but other times that's a big nope. My concern here is you're not joining, you're just selecting from two tables with a `WHERE`.

Comment: i have added an exaplain, hope that can help

Answer (score 2):

I would start by creating geography column in both tables, and saving the points there. Then add spatial index to both tables:
https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html
Do join using these indexed points, which should be faster.

Without index it is full cross join, and it is very expensive. With index it should work faster, although might still be a heavy query for a single box.